# Graphical artifacts on Dell Dimension 8300

Tags: windows-7, graphics-card, visual-artifacts

For the past few days, I have been working on fixing an old Dell Dimension 8300 tower I have.  I performed clean installations of Windows XP, Vista, and now Windows 7.

At first, my Windows 7 installation was working perfectly, until the computer rebooted and I began experiencing graphical artifacts -- particularly RGB lines during bootup and vertical black lines around the window and near the mouse cursor -- during bootup, while starting Windows, and while using Windows for normal operations.

In order to rule out issues with Windows 7 itself, I re-performed a clean installation of Windows Vista, which then began to yield the same sorts of artifacts I began experiencing with Windows 7.

Then, having ruled out operating system installation issues and issues specific to Windows 7, I reinstalled Windows 7 and used TeamViewer to view the computer remotely.  On the remote system, I can still see the graphical artifacts appearing on the Dell.  This rules out any issues related to my AOC monitor itself.

What I find odd, however, is that these issues seem embedded in system functionality.  Taking a screenshot of the Windows UI within Windows 7 shows the graphical artifacts in the image.

[image: Screenshot of black vertical line artifacts along taskbar and around program windows.]

Furthermore, while booting from a Windows 7 installation disc, RGB artifacting occurs during the "Windows is loading files..." screen.  However, the GUI for Windows 7 installation shows no graphical artifacting at any point during Windows 7 configuration and installation.

[image: RGB graphical artifacts during "Windows is loading files..." screen.]

Additionally, I should note that the monitor is a VGA monitor.  However, I tried using a DVI male to VGA female adaptor for the DVI input on the Dell's graphics card, yet still experienced the same issues.

I am thinking that the graphics card is starting to fail, though I am not sure as to whether or not this would cause the artifacts to appear within a screenshot of the Windows UI?

At this point, I am hoping someone might be able to offer a possible next step in attempting to solve this problem?

**Please note again** that the graphical artifacts appear in various forms during bootup (Dell loading screen, Windows 7 is starting screen), while using the Windows UI, and when loading the disc files for a new Windows installation. The only cases wherein I do not experience artifacting are while interacting with the BIOS and while configuring and installing Windows from a disc.

Comment: Put an exclamation mark like that ![image-description][1] so that you have an image in the post instead of a link.

Comment: @styrofoamfly new users simply cannot insert image links: https://meta.superuser.com/questions/94/new-user-limitations/98#98

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The graphics card is failing.

I was unaware of a Dell Diagnostics partition on my hard drive that, once discovered, I was able to use to test the hardware.

The diagnostic tool stated that there were issues in writing to the graphics card.  The error code generated also corresponds with other users' experiences regarding graphics card failures as described via the Dell Support website.